# leiningen - clojurescript equivalent of lein run?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojurescript

In clojure I can run:

```
lein run -m my.namespace # run the -main function of a namespace
```

and this will run my code from the command line.

Is there an equivalent for Clojurescipt to run the generated code in node.js? (In leiningen)

(I have read the doco for starting the Clojurescript REPL, for the running on node.js and the reply integrated into my application. I was just looking for a one-line command line solution.)

Comment: [lein-clojurescript](https://github.com/bartonj/lein-clojurescript) should help you out with compilation.

Comment: I'm fine with compilation - I'd like to execute the compiled code

Comment: execute it in what environment?

Comment: Thanks - have clarified environment

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your goal is, you might find it useful to use 'cljsbuild test'. You can specify a test context on your project.clj that uses node.js/v8/phantomjs.

Example:

```
:cljsbuild {
    :test-commands {
        "v8" ["v8"
              "target/generated-sources/private/js/client.js"
              "tests/v8-test-runner.js"]}}
```

v8-test-runner.js:

```
path.to.your.entrypoint.start()
```

You can also leave 'lein cljsbuild auto' running and start the javascript application directly:

```
v8 target/generated-sources/private/js/client.js tests/v8-test-wrapper.js
```

That's probably the best option if you are building a node.js application using clojurescript. You don't need to worry about classpaths in javascript (which is the major thing that lein run provides), you can just run your application directly from the assembled javascript file.